# How to log log level for each log in RoR application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want something like:

```
[INFO] User initiated request GET '/'
[ERROR] 500 Internal failure
```

I checked config.log_tags but I do not see an intuitive way to do this.

Note: One way I found is to override the Logger::add function. But would prefer a more standard way for this.

Comment: `Rails.logger.info('Just saying'); Rails.logger.error("You can do this!")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your rails application logger should print out the level of log

if you have a special rails application where this is not working you can initialize a `Rails.logger` with STDOUT

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.logger.info("test")
test
=> 5
# with STDOUT initializing 
irb(main):002:0> Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
irb(main):003:0> Rails.logger.info("test")
I, [2021-04-03T11:27:09.549395 #98808]  INFO -- : test
=> true
```

you can also configure your app per rails documentation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger